# Mysql Distinct function nested within other function in select

Tags: mysql

Is there a way we can use disctinct for below cd.date_id? It's getting concatenated but I would also like distinct function aswell so it's like `GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( distinct(cd.date_id) AS CHAR ) ) As date_id` but it does not seem to work...

```
SELECT b.bar_id, b.bar_name, b.bar_image, b.bar_lat, b.bar_lng, b.bar_address,  
       b.bar_phone, b.bus_web, b.bar_open_hours, c.coupon_id, c.coupon_text,  
       bc.coupon_start_time, bc.coupon_exp_time, 
       GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( cd.date_id AS CHAR ) ) As date_id,
       d.calender_date, bc.bc_id, bc.priority As priority 
       FROM bars b 
       JOIN bars_coupons bc ON (bc.bar_id = b.bar_id) 
       JOIN coupons c ON (bc.coupon_id = c.coupon_id) 
       JOIN calendardates cd ON (cd.bc_id = bc.bc_id)
       JOIN date d ON (d.date_id = cd.date_id)
       GROUP BY cd.bc_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` inside there would not make any sense. What do you want to do here exactly? It seems you want only one row per distinct `cd.date_id`.

If that's the case just add cd.date_id to your `GROUP BY` clause at the end. Like this:

```
GROUP BY cd.bc_id, cd.date_id
```

And as you are using MySQL, you need not worry about using aggregate functions on all selected columns, if they would have the same value in all rows Grouped by the Group By clause, if not MySQL will just pick the first one

**UPDATE**
Looking at documentation for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), you might be able to do it like this

```
GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CAST(cd.date_id AS CHAR) ) As date_id
```

Comment: The date_id is getting concatenated but I would like them to be distinct so it gets rid of all duplicates for each bc_id before concatenation

Comment: @user952543 for that try to add `cd.date_id` to your group by clause as i have suggested in my answer, while NOT using DISTINCT in the Concat. See if it works

Comment: that gives duplicate bar_id's I need distinct bar_ids with concate date_id